# Select the max,min of nested lists vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, nested

I have these objects

```
Public Class Class1
        Public Property Type As String
        Public Property SpecLimits As Limits
    End Class

    Public Class Limits
        Public Property MinValue As Double?
        Public Property MaxValue As Double?
    End Class
```

I can have more `Type`-s with their `Speclimits` values. I need to find the maximum of MaxValue. I can make it with a `for each` to check every time which number is bigger, but I thought maybe their is some `linq` with what this could be achievable.
I found something like this in `c#`

```
 var maxItem = emplist
.Select((emp, index) => new 
{ 
    maxProject = emp.project
        .Select((proj, pIndex) => new{ proj, pIndex })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.proj.ID)
        .First(),
    emp, index 
})
.OrderByDescending(x => x.maxProject.proj.ID)
.First();
```

but I can't translate it to `vb.net`
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *guess* you want something like this:

```
Dim minValue As Double = list.Min(Function(x) x.SpecLimits.MinValue)
Dim maxValue As Double = list.Max(Function(x) x.SpecLimits.MaxValue)
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. Thank you. It works as I expected.